# How Do I Stop SASS Duplicate CSS?

Tags: sass

I have the following SCSS.

```
.mat-tab-label { 
  &:focus {
    background-color: #1976d2 !important; color:white;
  }
}

.mat-tab-label-active {
  background-color: #1976d2 !important; color:white;
}
```

Both selectors need the same properties but how to I remove the duplication? Variables only store single values.

Answer (score 1):

Check out sass basics [here](http://sass-lang.com/guide)

Search for extend/inherirance section and mixin section. Both provide options to reuse your CSS rules across your sass files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [styles extending](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_extend__extend) functionality and [placeholder selectors](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Placeholder_Selectors___foo) to achieve your goal:

```
%tab-label {
    background-color: #1976d2 !important; 
    color:white;
}

.mat-tab-label { 
  &:focus {
    @extend %tab-label;
  }
}

.mat-tab-label-active {
    @extend %tab-label;
}
```